# Google map (geocoder.geocode) breaks the markers list while using address instead of LatLng

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

Chaps, 
Please Have a look at my google map from. It works while I am using LatLng for showing the location. the problem is using Geocode to convert address to LatLng.

although the marker shows up for only the first address , the Infowindow wont get attached to it. Also after the first address is reached in the loop it breaks and no more location or addresses are being shown. It shows all the location with latLng but miss behaves when reaches  addresses ( using geocode)

Link to the complete code is on : http://jsfiddle.net/6cs2uLrL/8/

```
  var clients_details;
  var infowindow =[];
  var content =[
                 'QLD marker','SA marker','WA marker','VIC marker','random marker'
                  ];
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var clients_details =
       [
         {location:"-26.6719304,153.0889225,17z",address: null},
         {location:"-34.927883,138.610688,17",address: null},                                             
         {location: null ,address:"Perth, WA"},
         {location: null ,address:"Melbourne, VIC"},
         {location:"-39.927883,150.610688,17",address: null}
       ];



   /**
   *
   * Draw google map with markers
   */
  function initialize()
  {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // Sydney
    var defaultLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

    var mapOptions =
    {
      center: defaultLatlng ,
      //disableDefaultUI:true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
      },
      zoom: 3
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    // Makes sure clients_details is populated
   if (clients_details != null)
      showMarkers(clients_details);
 } // initialize
 /**
  * Asigning info to the  markers on the map
  * @param {list} clients_details
  *
  */
 function showMarkers(clients_details)
 {

   var marker = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < clients_details.length; i++)
   {

       infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: content[i] });           
       var client_location='';
       if (clients_details[i]['location'] !== null)
       {
       // Geting Lat and Lng from the database string
       LatLng = clients_details[i]['location'].split(',');
       // Making number from string
       Lat = Number (LatLng[0]);
       Lng = Number(LatLng[1]);
       client_location = new google.maps.LatLng (Lat,Lng);
       marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: client_location,
         map: map,
         title:  'LatLng'
           });

       }
       else
       {

         client_address = clients_details[i]['address'];
         geocoder.geocode(
           { 'address': client_address},
           function(results, status)
           {
             debugger;
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
             {
               client_location = results[0].geometry.location;
               marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: client_location,
                 map: map,
                 title: 'address' 
               });
             }
             else
               alert('Geocode was not successful for the following\n\
                      reason: ' + clients_details[i]['name']+'\n' + status);
           });
       }
       // Add 'click' event listener to the marker
       addListenerMarkerList(infowindow[i], map, marker[i]);
   }// for
 }// function

 /*
  * Adds a click listner to the marker object
  *
  *   */
 function addListenerMarkerList(infowindow, map, marker )
 {       
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
      });
 }     

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First, at the end of the `for` loop you're calling `addListenerMarkerList(infowindow[i], map, marker[i]);`. However, if you're geocoding the location, `marker[i]` will only be created after the geocoder has returned (in your `function(results, status)` callback). To resolve this, you need to call `addListenerMarkerList` in the `if` branch as well as in the geocoding callback.

Second, in your geocoding callback `function(results, status)`, you're accessing the loop variable `i`. A `for` loop does, however, not create a new scope. That means that the value of `i` is not wrapped with your callback. When the callback is executed, the `for` loop will have finished and, hence, `i` will be equal to `clients_details.length`. The workaround is to use a function closure.

Conceptually, the fixed code looks like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLsyf9m5/)).

```
for (var i = 0; i < clients_details.length; i++) {
    ...
    if (clients_details[i]['location'] !== null) {
        ...
        marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker(...);
        addListenerMarkerList(infowindow[i], map, marker[i]);
    } else {
        ....
        geocoder.geocode(..., (function(i) {
            return function(results, status) {
                ...
                marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker(...);
                addListenerMarkerList(infowindow[i], map, marker[i]);
            }
        })(i));
    }

    //addListenerMarkerList(infowindow[i], map, marker[i]); // Will not work
}
```

Comment: Cheers Hennes. That works like a charm.
For me and maybe others who are  new to JS would you tell what do you relate those two mistakes so I can read more about them.
Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Sinaaria You're welcome. Concerning further reading, just google for `javascript callbacks` and `javascript closures`. There are plenty of resources but none that I could recommend in particular.